# export to excel with excel tagsets.

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am thinking to export the dataset's contents to an excelsheet by excel tagsets, 
However I am writing the code 5 times for 5 datasets.

I want to write a macro  which connects the list of variable from the library to the list of datasets so that I dont have to write the proc contents n number of times.

the basic code I wrote is like this:

```
    ods tagsets.excelxp file="c:\ECT2013_Mappning1.xls" style=statistical

      options( skip_space='3,2,0,0,1' sheet_interval='none' sheet_name='Datasets'     
suppress_bylines='no');

proc datasets library=work; quit;run;
 ods tagsets.excelxp options( skip_space='3,2,0,0,1' sheet_interval='none'    
sheet_name='Behtid' suppress_bylines='no');

Proc contents data=behtid varnum;run;
 ods tagsets.excelxp options( skip_space='3,2,0,0,1' sheet_interval='none' 
sheet_name='Biverk' suppress_bylines='no');

Proc contents data=biverk varnum;run;
 ods tagsets.excelxp options( skip_space='3,2,0,0,1' sheet_interval='none' 
sheet_name='Dosering' suppress_bylines='no');

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

and I want to write a macro which automatically connects the datasets and performs the excel tagsets with proc contents to the number of datasets available in the library. 
How do I do that?

Comment: Do you know how to write macros, and/or how SAS macros work?

Comment: Have you considered using the SASHELP.VCOLUMN table instead? Then you can use some of the ODS TAGSETS By options to automatically name sheets without creating a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Our macro should be callable with or without a workbook path, so the workbook path must be optional.
Sas macros know two types of parameters: positional mandatory (here used for the sheet) and by name optional (here for the workbook).

```
%macro excelOds(sheet, workBook=_same_);
    ods tagsets.excelxp 
        options(sheet_name="&sheet." 
                skip_space='3,2,0,0,1' sheet_interval='none' suppress_bylines='no')
        %if &workBook. NE _same_ %then;
            &excelOds file="&workBook." 
        %end;
    ; %* Do not remove this semicolon: it closes the ods statement;
%mend;
```

The first time we include the optional parameter, later we do not

```
%excelOds(Datasets,workBook=c:\ECT2013_Mappning1.xls);
proc datasets library=work; quit;run;

%excelOds(Behtid);
Proc contents data=behtid varnum;run;

** and so further **;

ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```